# Display Data in visual force page using angular

Tags: visualforce, angularjs

I have a below table

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in rows">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>
        <select ng-model="r.selectedObjectRowData"
            ng-options="option.apiName for option in objects"
            class="slds-select box hideOutlineClass" required="required">
                <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select ng-model="r.selectedFieldRowData"
            ng-if="r.selectedObjectRowData"
            ng-options="option.apiName for option in fields"
            class="slds-select box hideOutlineClass" required="required">
                <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to prepopulate the select with below data

```
 rows= [{"selectedValueRowData":"Outbound","selectedOperatorRowData":"Equal To","selectedObjectRowData":"Account","selectedFieldRowData":"Name","id":"xyz","filterLogic":"(1 AND 3) OR 2"}]
```

I get the last value in the prepopulate data but I cannot get  the select drop down to have the values. Can someone tell me how Can I achieve this using angular?

Comment: I'm new to angular but why is this <option value=""></option> empty? Or that's the piece you are stuck with?

Comment: Is `fields` an array of objects where each object has an `apiName` property?

Comment: yes Keith! I figured out the issue  I have to use option.apiName as option.fieldLabel for option in objects. and this did the trick. For @d_k it is to show empty default value.